# Fill dropdownlist with weeknumbers past 20 weeks

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I would like to have a dropdownlist, filled with the past 20 weeks (e.g.). The problem in this, is that possibly, another year is encountered. The function i wrote (see below) does work, as long as there is no stepping into a previous year.
Does anyone have an example that fills a dropdownlist or array with the past 20 weeks, taking culture into account?

```
   Private Sub LoadWeeknumbers()
        Dim ciCurr As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
        ' fill the combobox with the last 10 weeks
        ddlWeeknumber.Items.Clear()
        'then the 52 voorbije weken
        For i As Integer = 0 To 52
            Dim week As String = ciCurr.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now.AddDays(i * -7), CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday)
            Dim weeknr As String = week + "/" & DateTime.Now.AddDays(i * -7).Year.ToString()
            weeknr = weeknr.Replace("54/", "1/") 'for some reason 54 is in this loop, so we replace it

            ddlWeeknumber.Items.Add("Week: " & weeknr.ToString)
        Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
Dim week = GetIso8601WeekOfYear(DateTime.Now)
Dim year = DateTime.Now.Year
For i As Integer = 0 To 19
    ddlWeeknumber.Items.Add("Week: " + week.ToString() + "/" + year.ToString())
    If week = 1 Then
        week = 52
        year -= 1
    Else
        week -= 1
    End If
Next

Public Shared Function GetIso8601WeekOfYear(time As DateTime) As Integer
    Dim day As DayOfWeek = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetDayOfWeek(time)
    If day >= DayOfWeek.Monday AndAlso day <= DayOfWeek.Wednesday Then
        time = time.AddDays(3)
    End If

    Return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(time, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday)
End Function
```

Comment: This code seems too simplistic for what the OP is requesting. Actually the problem he is complaining about is when two years are involved; your code does consider an unified week-counter, not one per year. Unless I did misunderstood what the OP is expecting...

Comment: thanks for the reply!. This doesn't work. The problem is in the firstdayofweek, in the case of week 1/2014, this is MONDAY 30 DECEMBER and the weeknumber is set to 53, which is wrong. also changing to firstfourdayweek doen't solve this problem, but i am not sure why.

Comment: @real_yggdrasil as explained in my answer, this not an error; it results from certain rules you have to understand. But the question is: do you want one week counter per year or not?

Comment: @real_yggdrasil Yes there is a difference between the ISO8601 week and .Net week numbering. I've added code to handle that. Also if you want to include the year just handle that also in the if (year switch)

Comment: Hi varocarbas. i'm afraight i don't understand it very well then. What i want is that my list contains a list of the previous weeks based on a start date, so for 6/jan/2014, this list should contain: 2/2014, 1/2014, 52/2014, 51/2014 and so on. maybe i should not look at the week rules at all and create a for loop per year.

Comment: @real_yggdrasil then you would have to create your own collection (or edit the GetWeekOfYear values, as you are doing); it would output that 6/jan is 2nd week (and the previous week 53th/52th of december or 1st of january depending upon the day) or 1st week of january depending upon your configuration.

Comment: @real_yggdrasil anyway... as far as you seem to want to continue discussing here and the whole problem was the application of the GetWeekOfYear rules, I would better delete my answer as far as is not providing anything new.

Comment: @real_yggdrasil Added code to also display year in the dropdown

Comment: @varocarbas This code should handle year breaks fine, not sure what you mean?

Comment: My comment referred to your first code (the one taking just the first weekday and then relying on a simple counter for the remaining 19 weeks). PS: sorry for the delay in replying but I didn't get your message (despite the @ bit)?!

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes when the a year starts at the middle of the week, so the statement

`DateTime.Now.AddDays(i * -7)` will return with *last week of previous year* and miss *1 week of this year*

I rewrote the code to `VB.NET` as follows. This may solve the issue (Sorry, I'm not expert in `VB.NET`)

```
Private Sub LoadWeeknumbers()
    Dim ciCurr As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
    ' fill the combobox with the last 10 weeks
    ddlWeeknumber.Items.Clear()
    'then the 52 voorbije weken
    Dim weekOverlapped As Boolean = False

    For i As Integer = 0 To 52
        Dim date as DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i * -7)

        If date.Year <> DateTime.Now.Year And weekOverlapped <> True  
           date = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1)
           weekOverlapped = True
        End IF

        Dim week As String = ciCurr.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(date , CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday)
        Dim weeknr As String = week + "/" & date.Year.ToString()
        weeknr = weeknr.Replace("54/", "1/") 'for some reason 54 is in this loop, so we replace it

        ddlWeeknumber.Items.Add("Week: " & weeknr.ToString)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help!

I have succeeded creating the desired list, using a different approach. The result of the code below is the desired list, but without a 53/2013 item in it.

```
Private Sub LoadWeeknumbers()
    Dim currentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
    Dim week As Integer = currentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now, currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek)
    Dim weeksAdded = 0
    For i As Integer = week To 1 Step -1
        '  Dim week As String = ciCurr.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now.AddDays(i * -7), CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday)
        Dim weeknr As String = i & "/" & DateTime.Now.Year.ToString()
        weeknr = weeknr.Replace("54/", "1/") 'for some reason 54 is in this loop, so we replace it

        ddlWeeknumber.Items.Add("Week: " & weeknr.ToString)
        weeksAdded += 1
    Next i
    'now add another set of weeknumbers to the dropdownlist
    Dim nextDate = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year - 1, 12, 27)
    week = currentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(nextDate, currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek)

    For i As Integer = week To 1 Step -1
        If (weeksAdded < 53) Then
            '  Dim week As String = ciCurr.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now.AddDays(i * -7), CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday)
            Dim weeknr As String = i & "/" & nextDate.Year.ToString()
            weeknr = weeknr.Replace("54/", "1/") 'for some reason 54 is in this loop, so we replace it

            ddlWeeknumber.Items.Add("Week: " & weeknr.ToString)
            weeksAdded += 1
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```